# Youtube iFrame API events not firing on Firefox 14

Tags: javascript, youtube-api

I'm currently working on embedding a youtube video using the iframe API, what is annoying me is that the events are not firing only on Firefox (I have just tried firefox 14), they work on every other browser (obviously not using browsers from hell like IE7).

The samples from their documentation don't work either, if you grab the piece of code they have under the **getting started** section of [this page](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#Getting_Started) and [here](http://jsfiddle.net/aldoreyes/22txy/) is the jsfiddle version for your quick view.

The player is displayed on the page, but as I mentioned the events are not working, neither I can use any function from the api, they all throw undefined error.

I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok I found the problem,

It's because of the Firefox Extension HTTPS-Everywhere, which is switching the requests to use https, and since my page is requested using http, that was causing a conflict with the youtube iframe requests.

I believe I should put a warning on my site about using that plugin. Thanks for your help everyone.

Answer (score 0):

I had once a problem with plying events to the iframe and it also apeared only in Firefox.

The answer was to specify the `id` and `name` of the iframe to the same value.
Try it - it might work for you as well.